# Creacion de procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla para almacenar archivos

```
CREATE TABLE LFILES(
ID INT IDENTITY,
ID2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(255),
REALNAME VARCHAR(255),
CONTENIDO VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM,
EXTENTION CHAR(5)
);
--vamos a agregar archivos
INSERT INTO LFILES(ID2,NOMBRE,REALNAME,CONTENIDO,EXTENTION)
SELECT NEWID(),
'Name file',
'Real name',
BULKCOLUMN,
'extension'FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'ruta',SINGLE_BLOB) AS DOCUMENT
```

¿Cómo podría crear un procedimiento almacenado para el `INSERT`?

Comment: Toma: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/sqlserverya/ espero te sea de utilidad. Éxitos :D

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La primera pregunta: ¿Cuáles son las dificultades? Date a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Anexa el código que has intentado y el/los errores que te devuelve. Si es que se producen. Aquí tienes ejemplos de como se hacen [Create procedure](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)